# Nginx , Ssl slow website

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, vhosts

i installed my SSL to my website ( Nginx , SSL ) . After SSL my website is too slow. 
I could not find solution but it's related with ssl.

In same droplet i have 3 apps. 1 php ( laravel ) , 2 ruby ( ruby on rails )apps. But just one of them has SSL.

Conf file for my website with SSL :

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.guclukal.com;

  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  root /home/rails/trbodybuilding/public;

  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/guclukal.com/ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/guclukal.com/guclukal.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I use this steps to create SSL :

1.mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl

2. openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout guclukal.key -out guclukal.csr
3. i paste guclukal.csr to ssls.com to get files
4. cat guclukal_com.crt guclukal_com.ca-bundle > guclukal.crt to create crt file
5. than i made my nginx conf file .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It would be more on-topic at serverfault.com. But since it does not include any details about how the performance loss was measured and how much worse the performance is and shows no attempts to follow [performance tuning recommendations](https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+https+performance+tuning) I suggest to close it instead to move it.

Comment: instead of giving advise , try to solve problem :/

Comment: Instead of complaining about not getting the problem solved provide the information I mentioned as missing, try to follow existing recommendations to performance tuning and ask the question at the appropriate stackexchange site.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.